# Javascript unicode characters loop

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm trying to create a loop, to know a certain range of characters in unicode. For example if cyrrilic letters are ranged from 1040-1103 (according to `.charCodeAt()` method), I want to create a loop that would output unicode characters from that range. So far I've got this:

```
    for (var i = 1040; i < 1104; i++){
    document.write("\u" + i.toString(16) + "<br />");
    }
```

From what I've got, the outputing of a unicode character via `"\u0410"` (cyrrilic "A") wants a hex code of the character, when `.charCodeAt()` outputs a decimal value. I used `.toString(16)` here to convert the decimal value to hex, but it doesn't output anything for some reason, how can I do it so it would connect the "\u" with "0410"?

P.S: I tried adding `"\u0" + i.toString(16)`, because it seems that `"\u410"` won't work, but nonetheless, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you should avoid `document.write` if possible; It can cause race conditions and call `document.open` if the page has finished loading.

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, I'm just using it for learning purposes right now, I'm at the lowest level of basics of JS, but thank you for the advice.

Comment: You can try to feed ☞ this function two pairs of hex numbers: [Yet Another JavaScript Unicode Encode/Decode](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/yet-another-javascript-unicode-encodedecode/) have fun!  ☕

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the Unicode escape sequence you're using would have to be *inside* the string literal. `"\u0410"` and `"\u" + "0410"` are not the same thing. The first is a string literal containing a Unicode escape sequence. The second is a string literal with an invalid escape sequence, which we then try to append the string `"0410"` to.

To get a string with a single character for a given Unicode "character" (*mostly**), you use `String.fromCharCode`:

```
document.write(String.fromCharCode(i) + "<br>");
```

---

* Why I said *"mostly"* above: JavaScript strings are not made up of Unicode characters (surprising though that may be, as it usually *seems* like they are). They're made up of UTF-16 *code units*. (A code *unit* is not the same as a code *point*, "code point" is basically Unicode for "character," but a code *unit* may be only part of a character.) UTF-16 is a "transformation" of Unicode that uses 16-bit code units. For a *lot* of text (anything in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)), a single UTF-16 code unit can completely represent a Unicode character, but some characters require two code units (ones in [any of the other planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks)). Those characters show up as two "characters" in JavaScript strings. More in [the Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) on transformations, and in the links earlier. `String.fromCharCode` won't work correctly with values greater than 0xFFFF (e.g., more than an unsigned 16-bit integer).

Comment: Alternatively I think you can use: `document.write('&#'+ i +';');`

Comment: @KooiInc: Doh! [You're right, of course.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) I was so focussed on the JavaScript tree, I missed the forest. In HTML4 days, [in theory](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) that was only ISO-8859-1, but HTML5's spec broadens it to the full Unicode range with only a couple of exceptions. That's the better answer, frankly, for this specific use case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sometimes the world moves too fast ;) Before we know it, we're on the next track: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/next/markup/

Comment: Dull pedantry: `document.write` without the `&#` character reference is writing HTML, so may break for special characters like `<` and `&`. `document.write` with the character reference fails for characters in the range U+0080 to U+009F (because in HTML5 for compatibility reasons the character references in this range map to Windows code page 1252 codes). `String.fromCodePoint` in ECMAScript 6 will avoid the issues of UTF-16 in the future. HTML4 did support Unicode, it was 3.2 that was still based on ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @bobince: Thanks for all that, very good points about `document.write` and good news about ES6 (I hadn't seen that bit!). That last sentence is surprising, given the link I provided above (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), but it's not like it matters now. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since you seem interested, here’s some more info on Unicode problems in JavaScript and how ES6 helps to solve them: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode